# Is sagemath removed from Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: apt

I am trying to install sagemath by running :

```
sudo apt install sagemath
```

but it says:

> ```
> Package sagemath is not available, but is referred to by another
> package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
> obsoleted, or is only available from another source
> ```

I used toi be able to install sagemath this way...is there a fix for this ?

Many Thanks

Comment: sagemath has been removed from the Ubuntu 19.10 repositories and brought back in 20.04. It's got a lot of dependencies though. I don't know if you'd be able to install [sagemath for 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/sagemath) in 19.10 because of its dependencies.

Comment: From https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Sage: "*Some people within DebianScience have again packaged Sage for Debian. This is one of the most complex packages in Debian and will need continual maintenance - we are always looking for new contributors!*" If you really want sagemath to be available, consider contributing some effort to the Debian Science Team.